# How to implement long pooling stream using rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

1. I call `angularService.method1` for id, that I need for next request
2. I'd like to call `angularService.method2(id)` every second until I get the response `{success: true}` or:

   ```
   {success: false, errors: [{errorCode: 'code', errorMessage: 'some error message'}]
   ```

After hours of trying I came to this version, and actually it works. But I have some questions

1. Will the inner Observables be destroyed when main stream reaches "complete"?
2. Is it a proper implementation or maybe I have some issues here?

   ```
   this.angularService
   .method1(data)
   .flatMap((res) => {
       return Observable
           .interval(1000)
           .flatMap(() => this.angularService.method2(res.id))
           .concatMap(resp => {
               return (resp.success) ? Observable.of(resp, null) : Observable.of(resp);
           })
           .takeWhile(resp => resp);
   })
   .switchMap((res) => {
       return (!res.success && res.errors) ? Observable.throw(res.errors) : Observable.of(res);
   })
   .subscribe(
       (next) => console.log(next),
       (err) => console.log(err),
       () => console.log('finished')
   );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to call `method2` until you get the first response which is not null or undefined and then close the stream.

If this is correct, then I would start writing a function that receives the `id` parameter and then calls `method2` every second until it gets an answer, something like

```
callMethod2EverySecond(id) {
  return Observable.interval(1000)
         .mergeMap(() => this.angularService.method2(id))
         .filter(resp => resp !== null)
         .take(1)
}
```

This function does the following

- every second calls method2 with id as parameter - it is assumed that
  method2 returns either an object (with the correct response or
  an error) or null - consider that `mergeMap` is the new
  name of `flatMap`
- filters out all events which hold null via the filter
  `operator`
- takes the first of the events not null and closes the stream
  (this is performed by `take` operator)

Then you can use that function within the outer logic such as

```
this.angularService
.method1(data)
.switchMap(res => callMethod2EverySecond(res.id))
.subscribe(
    res => {
       if (!res.success && res.errors) {console.error(res)}
       else {console.log(res)}
    },
    (err) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('finished')
);
```

Consider these points:

- switchMap and mergeMap (or flatMap) in this case probably yield the
  same result, but are not the same ([read this for more details](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/))
- since your error condition can be deduced by analyzing the content of
  the response, you can do this directly in the first function defined
  as parameter of `subscribe` and you do not need to throw Observables
  as errors

**SAMPLE OF WORKING CODE WITH SIMULATIONS OF angularService.method1 AND angularService.method2**

The following is a working example of the code according to the above assumptions.

`method1` and `method2` of angularService have been simulated.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

method1('123')
.switchMap(res => callMethod2EverySecond(res.id))
.subscribe(
    res => {
       if (!res.success && res.errors) {console.error(res)}
       else {console.log('subscription processing', res)}
    },
    (err) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('finished')
);

function callMethod2EverySecond(id) {
    return Observable.interval(10)
           .mergeMap(data => method2(id, data))
           .do(resp => console.log('resp', resp))
           .filter(resp => resp !== null)
           .take(1)
}

function method1(data: string) {
    return Observable.of({id: data});
}

function method2(id: string, interval: number) {
    const ret = randomIntInc(0,1) === 0 ? null : {success: true, errors: null, interval, id};
    return Observable
            .of(ret)
            .delay(randomIntInc(0,2000));
}

function randomIntInc(low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
}
```

Comment: It is not crystal clear what Alexander wants to achieve, at least to me. you want to call method2 until you get the first response which is not null or undefined and then close the stream, this should work (unless I made a mistake - I can not test the code from where I am)

Comment: @Picci Not exactly. I want to call method1 only one time, as a result I receive some id. Then I want to call method2 and repeat calling method2 until I get the some result. It may happen on first call or 7, doesn't matter

Comment: @Alexander Ponomarev - I have edited my answer with a sample of working code where I have simulated method1 and method2 - the sample works fine, at least according to my understanding of how you want the behaviour to be